# Can .conda_trash files be safely deleted from Scripts folder in Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, anaconda3

I am using Anaconda python distributin. Under `Scripts` folder, I see several `~.conda_trash` files. Can these files be safely deleted?

I am using Windows 10, anaconda 2020_07.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .conda_trash file are generated on windows when conda tries to delete folder containing in-use files. As windows can't delete files that are in use (i think linux users don't meet the .conda_trash problem).

There is a delete_trash function at boot that scans the entire tree in search for those files and deletes them.

So basically conda should be able to get rid of those files by itself. But if those are not needed anymore (and take too much time at boot), it shouldn't be a poblem to manually delete them.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested on my PC that the `~.conda_trash` files can be deleted from `Scripts` folder without affecting anaconda distribution.